# Change to another View Controller when pressing cell of UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Hi I have a uitableview on my view controller and I want to go to another view controller when a cell is pressed, I read a couple of tutorial but all where from a table view controller.
Here is the code I have, it doesn't do anything when I pressed the cell.

EDIT:  I decided to create a custom button on the cell and from there go to the detail view

Here is what I put on the button, I get a thread 1: breakpoint 1.1 error on the second line:

```
- (IBAction)buttonSelected3:(id)sender {
UIStoryboard *storyBoard; storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

InfoFarmaciaViewController *vc = (InfoFarmaciaViewController *)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InfoFarmaciaViewController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to release the variable, ARC will take care of that. Just remove that line? And don't set it to null. Just push it, then you are done.

Comment: I remove the last two lines but still nothing wont change the view

Comment: Put a log statement in to see if your method is even getting called.. ?

Comment: I used the log, looks like is working calls the other view and also get's the correct information from the cell I selected but doesn't change the view

Comment: just put a `NSLog`in the `InfoFarmaciaViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method.... and see the `selectedfarmacias` value...

Comment: InfoFarmaciaViewController is the view controller I want to get to but when I select a cell on the view controller the table view is nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Are you using storyboard for that? - i assume not, change your views to storyboard and do the following:

UIStoryboard *storyBoard;
storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];

CustomViewController *vc = (CustomViewController *)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"idofthestoryboardview"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vid.fileViewController animated:YES];

Comment: I modify the original question and try to use the code you provided but I got an error I put it on the question.

Comment: thread 1: breakpoint 1.1 error on the second line, the new code is on the question.

Comment: maybe the name of the storyboard doesnt match..hahaha